# Using jQuery .val() to set the contents of a div

Tags: jquery

In my HTML:

```
< div id="textarea" style="overflow: scroll;"> < /div>
```

I'm trying to put a piece of javascript text which is set in var `X` into the textarea but whenever I do

```
$("#textarea").val(X);
```

nothing happens, whereas if I do

```
$("#textarea").text(X);
```

the text version of `X` shows up but not the formatting like `\n`.

How can I get `X` to show up properly in my textarea?

Comment: You're textarea is a regular div element, and not really a textarea element, so firstly it does'nt have a value attribute, it does however have content like any other element, but secondly, any escaped characters in the HTML content of an element will just show up like regular characters, as that is all they really are, and you should probably use tags instead, like `<br>` for linebreaks.

Comment: THANK YOU! :) haha, I didn't realize that. I made it an actual textarea and .val() works fine now. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 3):

`val()` is used for setting/getting the value of `textarea` and `input` elements, for `div` elements you should use `text()` or `html()`. If you want to add HTML markup you should use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method instead:

> Get/Set the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements.

```
$("#textarea").html(X);
```

Comment: the formatting still doesn't show up. 
var X = "o(._.)o\n" + 
 "  /|\\\n";
but what shows up instead is
o(._.)o /|\

Comment: @user1576449 if you want to show the format of text you should use `text()` method instead.

Comment: What I want is 
o(._.)o  


  /|\
(with proper spacing and linebreak)
Using .text() I end up with the same result as .html()

Comment: (sorry, there should be a linebreak between the o(._.)o and the  /|\)

Comment: @user1576449 Try this: ` X = "o(._.)o \n " + " /|\\ \n"` also for space you should code `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 2):

Naming a `div` textarea won't make it a `textarea`. Try this.

```
$("#textarea").html(X);
```

`val` is for input, textarea etc...

Answer (score 1):

use `.html()`

```
$("#textarea").html(X);
```